# android client Not able to authorize signalR request using bearer-token

Tags: android, authorization, signalr, signalr-hub, bearer-token

I am trying to connect signalR from the android client. I have already setup signalR hub and its working properly with javascript client on the browser. javascript client able to sent bearer-token and on the server side, I am able to get user identity.
But android java client is not able to send bearer token on. I am using https://github.com/SignalR/java-client library  (As I am not using SIgnalR-core so not using latest SIgnalR core library)

```
    connection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    connection.getHeaders().put("Authorization","Bearer XYZ");
    proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
```

When I run this code, I got an error

```
    java.lang.InterruptedException: Operation was canceled
```

But when I don't send AUthorization header with the request then on server-side SIgnalR OnConnected() method called successfully.

The issue seems to be with sending Authorization header with the request.

For reference, the following is code to show how token authentication is implemented on the server-side

```
     app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            map.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider()
            });
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                Resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver,
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
        ConfigureAuth(app);
```

I have tried calling it by removing authorization from the server. Then it called successfully. But not works when called with Authorization header.

When I tried connection without Authorization then on server-side OnCOnnected method called but Context. Identity is null.

android Java code for connecting to SignalR client

```
     Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
    // Create Connection
    connection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    connection.getHeaders().put("Authorization","Bearer XYZ");
    // Create Proxy
    proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
    // Establish Connection
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new 
    ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = connection.start(clientTransport);

    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Websocket, try this

https://github.com/doctorcareanywhere/java-client

build signalr-client-sdk and import the jar to your project

eg.

implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')